# Converting php array with attributes to XML

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on an XML library, that can create / parse xml's from arrays/jsons.
I managed to write the parser with xml_parser (and google help :p) cause SimpleXML wasn't good enough for what I'm doing.

I've managed to create an array that looks something like that:

```
Array 
(
[flow] => Array
    (
        [math] => Array
            (
                [apply] => Array
                    (
                        [lt] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [apply] => Array
                            (
                                [divide] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                                [apply] => Array
                                    (
                                        [minus] => Array
                                            (
                                            )
                                    )
                            )

                        [otherStuff] => 0
                    )

            )

        [true] => Array
            (


            )

        [true_attr] => Array
            (
                [xsi:type] => SomeStuff
                [id] => 2
            )

    )

[flow_attr] => Array
    (
        [id] => 0
        [xmlns:xsi] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
    )
)
```

As you can see, it should look something like this ( not the best example :p ):

```
<flow id="0">
 <math>
 <lalaa/>
  <appyl>
 </apply>
  </math>
</flow>
```

Note that empty arrays should end with /> for example  ,  and so on

As you can see I separated the node it self to node_attr that contains the attrs of the nodes. Like flow_attr, true_attr.

Anyone have an idea how to convert this array back to xml?
I'm just lost and don't know what to do.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This class is very useful for this kind of things: http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-php-array-to-xml-with-attributes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function recurse2xml ($array, &$string = "") {
    foreach ($array as $key => $subArray) {
        if (substr($key, -5) == "_attr")
            continue;
        $attrs = "";
        if (isset($array["$key_attr"]))
            foreach ($array["$key_attr"] as $attr => $value)
                $attrs .= " $attr='".str_replace($value, "'", "\\'")."'";
        if (empty($subArray)) {
            $string .= "<$key$attrs />";
        } else {
            $string .= "<$key$attrs>";
            if (is_scalar($subArray))
                $string .= $subArray;
            else
                recurse2xml($subArray, $string);
            $string .= "</$key>";
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
```

This function called with `recurse2xml($array);` expands your array tree into an xml tree (string form).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It didn't worked, but I'll try to fork it and move on from this.

Comment: @MichaelArenzon It outputs what I expect it to... but what are you expecting?

Comment: well there's a few syntax errors, and it doesn't support when there's a value, like in here:  [otherStuff] => 0 so I'm getting something like: <otherStuff><0></0></otherStuff>
and the attrs aren't showing from some strange reason :S
but thanks yet

Comment: @MichaelArenzon Okay, but how should it handle scalars? As a value? like `<otherStuff>0</otherStuff>`? The attrs are showing up locally...

Comment: yep, exactly.
Btw you can check out the parser I found here: http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/58/parse-xml-to-array-in-php

I've changed it a bit but the logic still the same

Comment: @MichaelArenzon Now better? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try [Array2XML](http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-php-array-to-xml-with-attributes/), worked flawlesly for me. Including CDATA Parts, etc.

Comment: Try to place this kind of things in the comments.

Comment: The site is down so this is worthless now. Would have been good to have the source code for the function in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function recursiveArrayToXml($array, &$return=""){
    foreach ($array as $key => $subarray){
        if(empty($key)) {continue;}
        $key = preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', '', $key);
        if(preg_match('/[0-9]/i',$key[0])){
            $key = 'x'.$key;
        }
        $return .= "<".$key.">";
        if(!is_array($subarray)){
            $return .= htmlentities($subarray);
        }else{
            recursiveArrayToXml($subarray, $return);
        }
        $return .= "</".$key.">\n";
    }
    return $return;
}
```

This function will similar to the posted above fix problems in element names and element values.
Called by recursiveArrayToXml($myArray);